# MPI implementation on multiple computers

Tags: mpi

I am very new to MPI. I am trying to ssh to another computer and trying to run a hello world program taken from this tutorial http://mpitutorial.com/mpi-hello-world/ as follows :

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment. The two arguments to MPI Init are not
    // currently used by MPI implementations, but are there in case future
    // implementations might need the arguments.
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Print off a hello world message
    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
    processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    // Finalize the MPI environment. No more MPI calls can be made after this
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I created a file `host_file` with 2 hosts, the localhost and and the ip address of the other computer. I tried to run this using:

> $ mpiexec -f host_file -n 2 ./mpi_hello_world

I am prompted to enter the password for the other computer. However the program execution hangs after this and nothing happens. I am able to ssh individually to both the PC's from one another. I have the exact files on both the PC's.

Comment: What MPI implementation are you using? Things to test. Can you run on just the localnode? Can you run on the remote node (just ssh in and exec with `localhost` in the node file)? If so then it's a communication error, if not, does the second host have MPI installed too?

Comment: Try `mpiexec -f host_file -n 2 hostname`. It should print the host names of the two nodes.

Comment: It is most likely a connection issue: I am getting this error now :  HYDU_sock_connect (./utils/sock/sock.c:174): unable to connect from "ubuntu" to "ubuntu" (Connection refused)                                [proxy:0:1@ubuntu] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:189): unable to connect to server ubuntu at port 47840 (check for firewalls!) ... how to correct this?

Comment: so you cannot ssh to yourself.  install an ssh server.